# jReject not working in IE7

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have installed the jQuery plugin jReject on a site I'm currently working on and need it to reject only IE7 and below. The plugin works perfectly for all other browsers but in IE 7 and below i get the following error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'reject'
```

The site I am working on is http://10.scopus.com and the code used to run the script is:

```
$(function(){
    $.reject({  
        reject: {  
            msie: 7 
        }  
    }); // Customized Browsers
});
```

and the site head looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/master.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/flexslider.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/jquery.reject.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/reject.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/s.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/jquery.reject.js"></script>
<script src="http://f.vimeocdn.com/js_opt/froogaloop2.min.js?bfeb60ee"></script>
<!--[if IE]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/modernizr.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score -1):

i checked your website.it works in document mode above 7 .
so we have to change document mode in your website.
use this,will work
add this script in your header

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

Comment: please use IE=8  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" >

Comment: press f12 in your IE.then change document mode to internet explorar 8 standard...check this is working or not?

Comment: Its works fine in IE 8, just not 7. Doesnt the code you have supplied only work when trying to make newer browsers work like older ones?

Comment: above script only change the mode ..IE=8 means you are using IE document mode 8 ...and your browser is still IE 7.....check by changing document mode,if it works then write in your website header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55309/discussion-between-sean-lang-and-mr7-itsurdeveloper).